# "Undefined reference" errors when including <iostream>

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I have started a new console application (C++) in Code::Blocks 17.12 with Cygwin compiler and g++ 7.3.0, and I have only "main.cpp" which have a very small code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout<<"test";
return 0;
}
```

I clicked build and got 16 errors, Here's the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in 1 (compiler: Cygwin g++)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++14 -IC:\cygwin\usr\include -c C:\Users\Windows7\Desktop\BASIL\1\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\cygwin\lib -o bin\Debug\1.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `__cxa_atexit'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001702.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_destroy'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001704.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_init'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001709.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_unlock'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001720.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_once'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001705.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_lock'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001699.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_key_create'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001697.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_getspecific'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001741.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_setspecific'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001679.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_wait'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001674.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_broadcast'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001700.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_key_delete'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001675.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_destroy'
C:\cygwin\lib/libpthread.a(t-d001677.o):fake:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_signal'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
16 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

I also edited the compiler, the linker and the resource compiler in search directories tab according to the documentation but that didn't work.
please help me in this! 
Thanks,

Comment: The problem is most likely caused by use of `g++.exe` for compiling and `mingw32-g++.exe` for linking.

Comment: Might need `-lpthread` to link in pthread support. Not up enough on Code::Blocks to know the path to the configuration pane that allows required libraries

Comment: I think it's a MinGw problem, I tried Cygwin and it's working, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally fixed it! Just giving the answer to people still searching, 
just install Cygwin and go to `settings -> compiler` in code::blocks and pick Cygwin GCC instead of GNU GCC compiler, go to the Toolchain excutables and change the "Compiler's Installation Directory" to your Cygwin directory and change the "Program files" to your cygwin programs (if they're not already modified), the compiler window should look like the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm1p2.png) attached.

Comment: Accept your answer.